# Pandas - How to add a value from the nearest row, then stop searching

Tags: python, pandas

If I have the following,

```
ValA ValB  ValC 
8    xxxx  NaN  
7    xxxx  NaN  
6    xxxx  1   
5    xxxx  NaN   
4    xxxx  NaN  
3    xxxx  1    
2    xxxx  NaN   
1    xxxx  NaN
```

Output Goal

```
ValA ValB  ValC ValD
8    xxxx  NaN  20
7    xxxx  NaN  20
6    xxxx  1    20
5    xxxx  NaN  6 
4    xxxx  NaN  6
3    xxxx  1    6
2    xxxx  NaN  3 
1    xxxx  NaN  3
```

What could I run on the initial dataframe to either set it to a specifc value obtained from a later row or 20. The value will be the the value from the nearest row meeting a certain criteria, In my Example when ValC = 1 use ValA in ValD. If it doesnt find a 1 in ValC before running out of rows then simply use the value 20.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What are examples 3, 2  and 1?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you are trying to do. What is exit date?

Comment: Simplified the question. Hopefully that is clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear what you want to do, but the code below will meet what you describe in your example:

```
In []: df
Out[]:
   ValA  ValB  ValC
0     8  xxxx   NaN
1     7  xxxx   NaN
2     6  xxxx   1.0
3     5  xxxx   NaN
4     4  xxxx   NaN
5     3  xxxx   1.0
6     2  xxxx   NaN
7     1  xxxx   NaN

In []: df['ValD'] = pd.np.where(df.shift(1).ValC == 1,  # Where upper row == 1
                                df.shift(1).ValA,       # Assign upper row's ValA
                                pd.np.nan)              # Else np.nan

In []: df.ValD = (df.ValD.ffill()                       # Propagate ValD values forward
                    .fillna(20))                        # Fill remaining with 20

In []: df
Out[]:
   ValA  ValB  ValC  ValD
0     8  xxxx  20.0  20.0
1     7  xxxx  20.0  20.0
2     6  xxxx   1.0  20.0
3     5  xxxx   1.0   6.0
4     4  xxxx   1.0   6.0
5     3  xxxx   1.0   6.0
6     2  xxxx   1.0   3.0
7     1  xxxx   1.0   3.0
```

Comment: Close enough, was able to modify and meet my needs. Thankyou!